# Create class Massive C#

Tags: c#

I need to create class Massive in C#, I tried this code, but it does'n work right

```
using System;

namespace Massiv1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("n = ");
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Massiv mas = new Massiv(n);

        mas.ShowAll();

        Console.Write("i = ");
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        mas.ShowElement(i);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Massiv
{
    public Massiv(int n)
    {
        int[] mas = new int[n];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; ++i)
        {
            mas[i] = rand.Next(0, 10);
        }
    }

    public void ShowAll()
    {
        foreach (var elem in mas)
        {
            Console.Write(elem + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void ShowElement(int index)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("index {0} mas{1} = ", index, mas[index]);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!");
        }
    }

    public int this[int index]
    {
        get { return mas[index]; }
        set { mas[index] = value; }
    }

    private int[] mas;
}
}
```

my method ShowAll doesn't work and I dont understand why. How to fix that?

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? it doesn't print what you want it? it gives you an error?

Comment: You need to give us more details. What are you trying to accomplish with this code? How does ShowAll not work? An error? An incorrect output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace

`int[] mas = new int[n];`

with

`mas = new int[n];`

You want to use your field - right now you're assigning data in the constructor to the local variable, which is not available in `ShowAll` method.

Comment: thanks a lot, now it works, and can u explain me why it helped? I really don't understand what was wrong.

Comment: your definition of int[] in your constructor created a local variable, which was disposed of after finishing the constructor's work, the value never reached your field, in order to use your class's fields, this is how you should access them.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

Remove the `int[]` prefix for your defintion `int[] mas` in your constructor, it creates a local variable blocking your (hard to find) definition of the field for the wanted `mas`.

**Edit 2:**
As I explained in the comment, this is how you define a variable , by doing so inside the constructor and not in the class itself, you created a local variable, not available after completing the constructor's work.

Another thing to note, it is better practive to define your fields/properties at the top of your class, this will save you from looking for hidden fields such as the case here.

Also, you should learn regarding class variables and local variables, I suggest having a look here:

[Variables and parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664639%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: After refreshing the page, I saw your change and removed my downvote :)

Comment: It is - look at the bottom of the code.